# Class-Wide `using` alias as return type issuing compiler error

Tags: c++11, gcc4.7

In order to keep some code readable and avoid typos, I'm using the following statement in the `public` section of a class definition in a header file:

```
using Assembly_Tuple = std::tuple <std::vector <std::string>, Trigger_Map, Attribute_Map>;
```

I'm declaring a function in the header file with `Assembly_Tuple` as a return type:

```
Assembly_Tuple merge_node_attributes(const std::string& node_name, std::string tmpl_name="");
```

And I'm defining the function in the source file:

```
Widget_Server_Interface::Assembly_Tuple 
Widget_Server_Interface::merge_node_attributes(const std::string& n, const std::string& t)
{
    //...
}
```

But when I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
src/WidgetServer/WidgetServerInterface.cpp:31:1: error: ‘Assembly_Tuple’ in ‘class Widget_Server_Interface’ does not name a type
```

However, inside definitions, there aren't any problems.

If I change that line to the egregious:

```
std::tuple<std::vector<std::string>, Trigger_Map, std::map<int,Node_Value>>
Widget_Server_Interface::merge_node_attributes (...) {...}
```

it's fine. Clearly the problem is using the alias outside of scope, even though it's public
and I'm explicitly calling on the class namespace.

I looked in Bjarne's book but he doesn't mention anywhere whether or not this is legal.

This is using gcc 4.7.

Mostly, I would just like to know *why* this isn't valid.

Comment: what if you are making it a `typedef`, does that work?

Comment: I had some similar problems with gcc. using `typedef` usually works when `using` doesn't.

Comment: I haven't tried a typedef, to be honest. I've been trying to upgrade my code base to C++11 wherever possible (been reading the 11 edition of Bjarne's book, and it's been inspiring). I guess, though, if it's something that *should* work but doesn't it's a gcc problem, which definitely answers my question.